# Protractor 5.1.2 - addMockModule does not return any output (and not injecting module)

Tags: angularjs, testing, ionic-framework, protractor, integration-testing

I am working on the E2E tests for an Ionic v1 app written in Angular 1.x + with Component oriented pattern (Webpack + ES6).

I am trying to add a mock module via the `browser.addMockModule` function but with no success.
I have tried everything, including adding the mock before `browser.get`etc.

Here's a simple test (in the onPrepare function, but it was in a specific test BeforeAll at an earlier stage, with same result):

```js
   browser.addMockModule('myMockModule', () => {
            console.log("mock is being executed");
            return;
        });

        browser.pause();
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100');
```

The actual code I am trying to implement is supposed to ovveride an existing module of my application.

```js
   console.log('beforeAll --> proof-of-delivery');
    browser.addMockModule('myOverridenModule', () => {

        console.log('beforeAll -->addMockModule proof-of-delivery');

        angular.module('myOverridenModule', ['ui.router'])
        .run( ($state, $rootScope) => {     

            console.log('myOverridenModule override');

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, toState) => {
                console.log('toState test ', toState);
              });

        });
    }); 

    browser.pause();
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100');
```

Any suggestion on what could possibly be wrong? On a side note I have already checked also the actual**Chrome console logs** and the terminal ones. No logs from the module anywhere at all (but I can see the log immediately before invoking the function).

Thanks for any help you can give in resolving such an issue. My stress will be grateful.

Comment: No matter if I try the simple test or the actual code I need tor run, the log does not get produced. even debugger; commands are not triggered. It looks like the code does never get reached.

Comment: Why not just run your application locally then test off that url?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire what do you mean? Consider that I have to expand that mock. I have to override an existing listener and check for a specific state. If in test mode, I have to prevent transition to that state and mock a few things. So don't pay too much attention to the body itself, nany clues on why the mock does not get created? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your problem is that you are using

```
browser.driver.get('http://localhost:8100');
```

this is wrapped browser instance and not the protractor browser instance so any mockModules defined will be ignored.

If you use

```
browser.get('http://localhost:8100');
```

your mockModules should be executed.